# redirect user, then log his visit using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, statistics, tracking

I have a PHP redirect page to track clicks on links. Basically it does:

```
 - get url from $_GET
 - connect to database
 - create row for url, or update with 1 hit if it exists
 - redirect browser to url using Location: header
```

I was wondering if it's possible to send the redirect to the client first, so it can get on with it's job, and then log the click. Would simply switching things around work?

Comment: Is what you are doing very time critical?  I don't think that you are really loosing that much time by doing it the way that you are.

Comment: I agree with Mark, SQL insert statements are usually quite fast.  In fact, you could make a Stored Procedure that preforms your Create/Update logic.  All you would need is one CALL statement.

Comment: Yes, setting a "Location" header does not terminate the running script, so it works in that sense - you should also call flush() after setting the header so it gets sent immediately to the browser.

Comment: No, what I'm doing is not very time critical. However, it's a hobby project, not work, and it's just fun to get things as fast/efficient as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

1. get url from `$_GET`
2. send `Location:` header
3. call [`flush()`](https://www.php.net/flush)
4. connect to database
5. create row for url, or update with 1 hit if it exists

This will not necessarily cause the browser to go on its way immediately, since your connection is still being held open and what the browser does about that is up to it, but (barring conditions that cause `flush()` to not work) it will at least get the `Location:` header out to the browser so it can do the redirect if it likes.

If that's not good enough, I'd recommend dumping your data to per-minute or per-second files that a script then picks up for postprocessing into the database.  If *that's* not good enough, you can play with [`pcntl_fork()`](https://www.php.net/pcntl_fork); this is an *extremely* hairy thing to do under Apache SAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Most databases give you the ability to insert a query delayed, so it'll only process when the database is idle.  You're most likely best doing that...so long as the data isn't critical (you'll lose the query if mysqld dies or the RAM is flushed).
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html

Answer (score 0):

That is fine. PHP will finish executing before flushing the redirect header to the client. If you still have doubts try saving this in a file and loading from browser:

```
<?php
header('location: /');
sleep(2);
?>
```

The redirect should not happen for 2 seconds.